# Executing a process with Process.Start() using the path of the process

Tags: c#, path

I'm doing this:

```
public static void ExecProcess(String path, string filename)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = path + "nst.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = filename;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    var stringa = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    proc.Close();
}
```

The problem is my process is using the path of my C# application and not its path. So `nst.exe` is in `C:\Desktop` but when I call it with the code above the execution path became `C:\\Documents\VisualStudio\MyProject\Debug\`.

How can I execute the process in his path?

[EDIT]
This is how I call the method:

```
    public void EseguiOttimizzatore()
    {
        OttimizzatoreService.ExecProcess(@"C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\", _idPlanning.ToString() + ".dat");
    }
```

Comment: how are you passing `path` to your method.

Comment: @Habib `@"C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\"`

Comment: share your method calling code(to identify How you are passing PATH), so that we can identify the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `WorkingDirectory` property of `StartInfo`:

```
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\";
```